# Genre, Developer of IPhone Application displayed in ITunes,Apps

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

If one opens ITunes, go to Apps and displays the apps as a list. 
You can see the name, developer, genre and the size.

I want to distribute an IPhone Application for the Enterprise In-House-Store.
After I shared my IPhone Application, I can not submit or validate the IPhone Application, because I don't have an app-store access.
Now I want to give my application a genre name like "IPhone games" or "Livestyle" and a developer name like "Amazon" or "EA Games".
Where can I enter these information in my IPhone Application or Xcode Project?

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere, this information is set during the upload process and has nothing to do with your xcode project per se. For more information please consider reading the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf).

Comment: Do I have a ITunes Connect Account, when I have a apple enterprise enrollment for in-house distribution?